# Spring JPA Multiple "schema-xx.sql" files?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing Spring Boot / -JPA application. By default, Spring-Boot loads "data-${platform}.sql" and "schema-${platform}.sql" automatically when the application is started. I found several notes about how to split a single "data-${platform}.sql" file into multiple files and how to use these "data"-files from Spring Boot. But what about "schema-${platform}.sql" files? My current "schema-${platform}.sql" has become quite large and thus confusing. The question now is, if I can split these "schema-sql" file into several files and what do I have to configure in my corresponding JPA classes? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you use FlyWay or Liquibase? They are more powerful and support migrations

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've used Liquibase before. I will have a look at it, but actually I don't want to have to use a separate tool for every little problem.

Comment: It's as separate as the data and schema files. One is implemented by Spring Data and one by Liquibase. It's also in the standard configuration of Spring. Have a look at the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool